# Simplifying a circuit to measure current

Tags: current, analog

So I'm to calculate the current in the places I put the ammeters in (yeah, I reckon one of them is turned around :)):

[image]

And while I can calculate such things for series or parallel circuits, I was taught I should first try to simplify the circuit and do it with Ohm's law and supplementary resistance. So I did something like that (which is my only idea):

[image]

And, regretfully, the results in the simulator are different. Then, how can I evaluate the 3 Ohm resistor (the one being "vertical" in the first picture) to somehow simplify the circuit and be able to calculate it? Could you please help? :)

Comment: Your prof/teacher has been clever and has designed a circuit that can't be solved by simplification.  In short your "equivalent circuit" isn't equivalent at all.  This circuit is solved using nodal or loop analysis

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot - will try to read on it a bit, I guess he won't demand the papers from us tomorrow since we haven't covered anything past simplifying and doing the equivalent circuit :) Thanks again!

Comment: @rawb: Actually there is some simplification possible if you look at pieces of the circuit at a time.  This is really not that hard to solve in a minute or two with a calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is homework, I'm not just going to give you the answer, but I will show you a method for attacking this problem.  I'll use the same designators rawbrawb did.  Whenever you show a schematic, add designators to make it easy to talk about.  We don't want to be saying "the second from top resistor next to the switch" or something.

[image]

Immediately you should be able to see that this circuit has two parts, the mess of stuff formed by R1-R5, and R6.  These two parts are in series.  R6 is already as simple as it gets.  You should be able to see that R1-R5 is equivalent to a single resistor from the rest of the circuit's point of view.  Once you have the equivalent formed by the R1-R5 mess, you have two resistances in series and the solution should be trivial.

The problem now gets down to solving the equivalent resistance of the R1-R5 circuit.  This you can break down into pieces.  Pretend a 1 V source is applied to this circuit.  If we can find the current drawn from that 1 V source, we can find the equivalent resistance by Ohm's law.

Start out by taking away R3.  Now you just have two voltage dividers, R1-R4 and R2-R5.  Each of these can be simplified into a Thevenin source.  From inspection, you can see that the R1-R4 source is 1/2 V and 2 Ω.  You can also see that the R2-R5 source is 2/3 V, and 2 seconds with a calculator tells you the resistance is 1.5 Ω.  Now you can put R3 back between the two Thevenin sources:

[image]

At this point you should be able to solve for the voltages at each side of R3 easily.  Once you have those, you go back to the R1-R5 circuit with 1 V applied and figure out the total current.  From the total current, you can find the equivalent resistance.  with the equivalent resistance of R1-R5, you go back to the original circuit and solve the total current.

Comment: Thank you for not using ugly CircuitLab schematic editor :)

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkCAr2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a more standard way of drawing the schematic, it might help you understand the problem better.