# How to efficiently compute the current at each node in a resistor network

Tags: circuit-analysis

I encountered a academic research problem to efficiently compute the current/voltage at each node of a rectangular resistor network. The rectangular resistor network that I have is defined by two things 1) the regular network topology, which you can consider it like meshgrids with one unit resistor on each edge; and 2) the knowledge of the state of each node (bad or good). For example, a 2x2 resistor network of my type (with all good node) is

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP8PIT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

3x3 resistor networks of my type with all good nodes and one bad node(2,0) are given below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpEpGn.png)</sup>

In practice, a resistor network I might have to deal with is of size 300x500. I wonder whether there is some efficient method to compute the current/voltage at each node, when the good/bad nodes are known and the two nodes connected into the circuit is (0,0) and (299,499). I guess there should be some existing methods to this type of questions. Can anyone kindly help me?

Comment: Are all resistors the same value?

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/60458/17592 - with a general answer: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/60468/17592

Comment: Is a tool like Spice an option?

Comment: Current isn't measured at nodes. Voltage is measured at nodes, current is measured in loops. Net current at a node is zero and net voltage around a loop is zero.

Comment: Probably nobody is answering this because it is a classic Mesh/Nodal analysis but with a huge number of meshes making it tedious.  Basically you wind up with a large system of equations, but there will be a pattern you can extract once you get started so you won't have to write out the whole 60,000 equations.  Try researching Mesh Analysis, or Nodal Analysis.

Answer (score 1):

In short you could do this by writing out the equations, but matrix algebra was invented so thousands of equations didn't need to be written out.

Here is a [paper](http://www.wiete.com.au/conferences/2wctee/papers/15-13-Zegarmistrz-P.pdf) describing how this can be done assuming you know something about matrices. At this level its basically somewhere in between a circuit model and finite element method model.