# Basic rules to calculate the equivalent resistance of a resistor circuit

Tags: resistors, basic

I have a certain circuit only containing resistors of different values. There is one 'input' and one 'output' for the current. How do I calculate the equivalent resistance of the circuit? Are there any basic rules to follow?

Comment: This question is intended to be linked to from examples of this question, such as http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/60458/17592 and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/60976/17592.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If determining replacement value is the only goal then I can think of the following steps:

1) Analyse the circuit into the smallest solvable sub-circuits possible (series and parallel);

2) Calculate series resistors \$R_S = R_1 + R_2\$;

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPTNKV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

3) Calculate parallel resistors: \$R_P = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_3}+\frac{1}{R_4}}\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp67dV.png)</sup>

4) Apply [wye-delta (Y-Δ) transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) or reverse

5) Repeat until solved or run the circuit through a circuit simulator like SPICE.

## Wye-delta (Y-Δ) transform

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIsZPW.png)</sup>

### Y→Δ

$$R_{ab} = R_{an} + R_{bn} + \frac{ R_{an} \cdot R_{bn} }{ R_{cn} }$$

$$R_{ac} = R_{an} + R_{cn} + \frac{ R_{an} \cdot R_{cn} }{ R_{an} }$$

$$R_{bc} = R_{bn} + R_{cn} + \frac{ R_{bn} \cdot R_{cn} }{ R_{an} }$$

### Δ→Y

$$R_{an} = \frac{ R_{ab} \cdot R_{ac} }{ R_{ab} + R_{ac} + R_{bc} }$$

$$R_{bn} = \frac{ R_{ab} \cdot R_{bc} }{ R_{ab} + R_{ac} + R_{bc} }$$

$$R_{cn} = \frac{ R_{ac} \cdot R_{bc} }{ R_{ab} + R_{ac} + R_{bc} }$$

Comment: This is a good answer, straight to the point. Perhaps clarifying with examples and an explanation of wye-delta would make it even better? :-) (I meant this to be easily understandable for beginners, and think they will yike seeing that wiki :-))

Comment: Ooh, cool. Wish I could upvote you some more for that edit!

Comment: In Dutch it is called "ster-driehoek transformatie" (star-triangle transform).

Comment: driehoek always makes me smile. Three-Corner!

Comment: @StaceyAnne Oh, it's a horror, really. For every mathematical term we have a different one. Fault of [this guy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Stevin). Driehoek isn't that bad, triangular is basically three-corner as well. But why do we have to call mathematics wiskunde (science of that what's true)!?