# How to calculate a simple mixed parallel/series resistor circuit

Tags: resistors

I'm trying to understand how to calculate resistance in simple mixed parallel and series resister circuit.  Below is a question from [a worksheet](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/worksheets/dc_sp.html) I've been playing with to better understand the topic (Question 5 ->Figure 6).

[image: Simple Resister Circuit]

I can see the 220Ω and 100Ω resistors are in parallel, but I do not understand how to break out and calculate the 470Ω and 330Ω resistors.

The answer given is 80.54 Ω, but I cannot seem to reach this on my own.

How do I calculate the resistance between points A and B?

Source:
[AllAboutCircuits.com - Series-Parallel DC Circuits Worksheet](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/worksheets/dc_sp.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/60977/17592

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try re-drawing the schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1e0fz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hopefully the solution will be obvious once you do so (comment/ask if it's not).

Comment: This was very useful, thank you.  Will absolutely try redrawing first in the future.  Next on my list is LaTeX, but here is what I ended up with that worked exactly as expected:  Resistance = (1/((1/((((1/((1/350)+(1/470)))+220)))+(1/100))

Comment: You're answer led me to another question regarding the location of the 470 ohm resistor. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/62263/why-doesnt-the-relocation-of-this-resistor-not-effect-the-circuits-total-resist