# Why doesn't the relocation of this resistor affect the circuit's total resistance?

Tags: resistors

Why does moving the 470Ω resistor in these examples have no effect on the total resistance between A and B?

[image: CircuitLab Schematic 9vm678]

This is a new question regarding the answer [given here by @helloworld992](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/62260/how-to-calculate-a-simple-mixed-parallel-series-resistor-circuit/62261?noredirect=1#62261).

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/60977/17592

Comment: The circuits are functionally identical. Even the node label B points to exactly the same thing in both schematics: the junction of R2, R3 and R4. If you read a lot of schematics, your brain will slowly become "blind" to seeing these kinds of things as different.

Comment: I don't understand why you essentially ask the same question after your original one has been answered properly. This is nearly a duplicate.

Comment: There is no 'resistor relocation' here, electrically speaking.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

470Ω is connected to node B in either picture.

Wires are assumed ideal conductors.  Both circuits are identical.  They have the same *topology*.  They are only drawn differently.

Answer (score 11):

Simply because you're not actually moving the resistor in the circuit.

The wire running past point "B" is a 0Ω connection. As such, no matter what side of B you connect R8 to, it's still effectively the same circuit.

Answer (score 4):

I've redrawn the two circuits with the interesting connections pulled away from their node.  Since anything joined by a wire is considered to be at the same potential, this should illustrate that it doesn't matter where the other end of R16 is connected.

[image: op's circuit with extra wires in red]

I've added rather more wire than is necessary, but it should help reinforce the idea that you can connect anywhere on the red traces.

Answer (score 1):

your drawing the same circuit but with different drawings, B on  both drawing is connected to directly (or through zero resistance wire) to the same node

Answer (score 0):

Two schematics of one circuit.
Both are the same ...